# Understanding SVG path in material design icon

Tags: svg, icons, material-design

I am a newbie in SVG world and was looking at some of the Google Material design icons ([link](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/)). Specifically the **clear** icon ([icon link](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/content/svg/design/ic_clear_24px.svg)).

I tried to create the same icon using SVG. Although in JSFiddle both icons look same, I think I'm missing something as the path in my version is a little bit concise. Can someone please explain why path has much more detail in later?

```html
<!-- My version -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M1 1L15 15M8 8L15 1L1 15" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="16" height="16" fill="none" />
</svg>

<!-- From Google Material design -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M19 6.41l-1.41-1.41-5.59 5.59-5.59-5.59-1.41 1.41 5.59 5.59-5.59 5.59 1.41 1.41 5.59-5.59 5.59 5.59 1.41-1.41-5.59-5.59z" />
  <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could actually make yours smaller

```
M1 1L15 15M15 1L1 15
```

The reason yours is different is because you are drawing your cross with strokes (thick lines).  The Material Design one is tracing the outline of the shape.  If you make it bigger and add a stroke colour you will see the difference:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M19 6.41l-1.41-1.41-5.59 5.59-5.59-5.59-1.41 1.41 5.59 5.59-5.59 5.59 1.41 1.41 5.59-5.59 5.59 5.59 1.41-1.41-5.59-5.59z" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

Why do they do it that way?  For various reasons.  It's a simpler approach to be consistent with how you represent shapes. If you want to change the icon colour you only have to change one property.  Also, fonts only use outlines, so icon sets that use strokes wouldn't be able to be converted to a font.